# Create item from InfoPath form TO SharePoint calendar, then delete from calendar if form deleted or updated?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

I created multiple InfoPath forms for different types of calendar requests (out of office, vacation, holidays, etc).  I then have a calendar that all the requests copy to, which I created from a SharePoint designer workflow that creates an item on the calendar when someone submits one of the InfoPath forms.

My question is how can I create a workflow to update that request on the calendar if someone were to either update their form, or delete it completely?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a "Wait for a change" activity to monitor for any change, e.g. Modified is usually enough, and use it to update whatever data needed?

It shall be more tricky for Deletions however.

Comment: No, I've never used Wait for change before. But that does make perfect sense. If I choose "Modified" for the first field, how would I end that activity? It doesn't make sense to put "is equal" to something.  Can you show an example? I've seen before, and tested, a way to delete from the calendar once the form has been deleted. However I accidentally deleted that test workflow. Now I cannot find the forum that I found the directions. So hoping someone can help me!

Comment: You could use Modified, or your an actual field. Compare with current date - http://sharepointresourcecenter.com/sharepoint-workflow-actions-wait-for-field-change-in-current-item.html

Comment: I'm just now able to get back to this project, it was on-hold for awhile.
I used the SPD action as you described it, which is now shows "Wait for Modified to equal Today" and then I added the action "Update item" and chose the calendar item to update.  I am still doing something wrong though, as it is not updating on the calendar.  I chose the same fields in the list to be updated (Title, Start date, End date, etc).  Any idea on what I may be doing wrong?  
Thanks for your help!